# Constantly running service while in app

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an app that pushes user's geolocation to the server *(with regards to permissions, of course)*.
Currently, when the user navigates to the account page, a method is invoked to push their geolocation to the server.
Instead, I would like a service *(if that's the best method)* to run while the app is running that will push the geolocation. This means that the location held for the user will always be up to date and not just updated when the account page is visited.

There is a `checkbox` on the account page where they select if they want to share their geolocation or not.
I have a `$watch`er on the checkbox...

```
$scope.$watch("account.shareLocation", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        locationService.pushLocation(userPosition);
    } else {
        locationService.pushLocation(null);
    }
});
```

So, if the user selects to share their location *(`newValue === true`)* then, `pushLocation()` should be constantly invoked with the `userPosition` until the value of  `account.shareLocation` *(the checkbox)* is altered otherwise.

Comment: I think you'd have to at least set an $interval for how often it should poll. You could easily create a service that uses $interval for updating their location. Start the service when the app inits and the $interval should do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/2/

You have your main controller that inits the service if the user has allowed it (I also added a mock `$timeout` of them unchecking it).

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $timeout, LocationService) {
  console.log('app init');

  //-- on checkbox change and/or app init;
  var trackLocation = true;
  if (trackLocation) {
    LocationService.start();

    //-- imitate them turning the service off
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log('stop tracking location');
      LocationService.stop();
    },10000);
  }  
});
```

Now for your service you could do something like this:

```
app.service('LocationService', function($interval) {
  var int;
  return {
    start: function() {
      int = $interval(this.saveLocation,3000);
    },
    stop: function() {
      $interval.cancel(int);
    },
    saveLocation: function() {
      console.log('save location');
    }
  }
});
```